# New Car battery car won’t start

Tags: battery, nissan, pathfinder

I bought a new battery for my 2006 Nissan Pathfinder, I put it in went to start the car and it started perfectly. I drove the car around for like 25 min. When I arrived back home I turned the car off and tried to start the car again but this time it didn’t want to start (no clicking noise as it did with the bad battery), the lights inside the car dimmed as well. Does anybody know what the problem might be or if you have ever experienced the same thing how did you fix it. Thanks.

Comment: You say the old battery was bad, and that's why you bought a new one, did you get the alternator checked to make sure it's charging the battery?

Comment: Loose or dirty battery cables?

Comment: Can you jump start it?